# Git taking old credentials on commit even after changing to new account

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have changed my git credentials in Windows Credential Manager ,Eclipse secure store, Git BASH . However on commiting my files , I still see my old id being picked up against that commit.

Can you please help.

Comment: Can you include the steps you took with the credential manager and bash?

Comment: For Windows Credential Manager --> Start -->Control Panel --> Credential Manager --> Git

Answer (score -1):

Git associates whichever username you have specified in your config with your commits - this is completely independent of the credentials you use to push commits to a remote.

Set it with

```
git config --global user.name your_username
```

https://help.github.com/articles/setting-your-username-in-git/